# Make Matplotlib map plots line up with each other

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I'm trying to produce a figure in Python that will display (among other things):

A) A basemap transformed from a Mercator projection image

B) Labelled gridlines

I would like the figure to be in the Transverse Mercator (or other spherical) projection.

I have tried both Matplotlib Basemap and Cartopy. Cartopy can do (A), and Basemap can do (B), however Cartopy can only label gridlines on PlateCarree plots, and Basemap does not support transformation of images using `imshow()`.

Unless someone can suggest another alternative, I think the simplest way around this would be to overlay the gridlines and labels from a Basemap plot on the reprojected image. However I cannot get the two plots to line up with each other. What I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

#Setup figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

#Set figure limits (lat long)
xlimits = [25, 42]
ylimits = [25, 40]
#Where the projection is centred
centre = [33, 33]

#Image limits in Mercator Eastings and Northings
imxlimits = [25, 42]
imylimits = [25, 40]
#Transform image Limits
imextent = tuple(ccrs.Mercator().transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(),
    np.array(imxlimits),  np.array(imylimits))[:, 0:2].T.flatten())
#Load image
image = plt.imread(Dir + 'topo.png')

tm = ccrs.TransverseMercator(central_longitude=centre[0], central_latitude=centre[1])
ll = ccrs.Geodetic()

#Setup image axies
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=tm)
ax.set_extent(xlimits + ylimits, ll)          #<--Limits defined here

#Plot image transformed
ax.imshow(image, origin='upper', extent=imextent, transform=ccrs.Mercator())

#Create axes for gridlines
axl = fig.add_subplot(111)
#Make the figure background transparent
axl.patch.set_alpha(0)

#Make basemap instance
m = Basemap(projection='tmerc', resolution='h', ax=axl,
    lat_0=centre[1], lon_0=centre[0],
    llcrnrlon=xlimits[0], llcrnrlat=ylimits[0],    #<--Limits defined here
    urcrnrlon=xlimits[1], urcrnrlat=ylimits[1])

m.drawcoastlines() #to check if the images match up
#Draw gridlines
m.drawparallels(np.arange(20, 50), labels=[False, True, False, False])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(20, 50), labels=[False, False, False, True])

plt.show()
```

[image: Plots with missmatched coverage]

This produces the plots roughly on top of each other but with a missmatch. I think this is because the limits given for the first plot might be set for the top and bottom edge, and the (same) limits given for the second plot are for the top right and bottom left corners.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Great question! Maybe add a cartopy tag? I've had problems aligning MPL.Basemap projections with other data as well. I've always assumed it was my error in not selecting the correct spheroid or projection parameters, but I've begun to feel like Basemap has some bugs in this department (e.g. [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/192)).

Comment: Ok, glad to hear its not just me having problems. I guess its possible that they are using a different method to convert to axis co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it to work by replacing how the Cartopy limits were defined, instead of:

```
ax.set_extent(xlimits + ylimits, ll)
```

I first converted to Transverse Mercator coordinates:

```
tmlims = tm.transform_points(ll, np.array(xlimits),  np.array(ylimits))
```

And then set the extent to this:

```
ax.set_extent([tmlims[0][0], tmlims[1][0], tmlims[0][1], tmlims[1][1]], tm)
```

As the plot is already in Transverse Mercator coordinates I don't know why doing the conversion manually made a difference (as defining `ll` rather than `tm` should do the same conversion). Maybe I'm misunderstanding how it does the conversion of the limits.

On the way to finding this solution I also found out about these bits of code that might help people with other 'Maps not lining up' problems:

```
ax.get_extent(crs) #Return the extents of the Cartopy axies in the given co-ordinates
#
#These work with any matplotlib axies
ax.set_anchor('W') #Anchor the plot to the left (in this case) of the canvas 
ax.set_aspect('equal') #Distort (or not) the aspects of the plot
```

See http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html and http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.4/matplotlib/geoaxes.html